# Congratulate someone on the forthcoming new year

Tags: phrase-request, translation

In Russian we say, "С наступающим Новым Годом!" What's the English equivalent? How do you congratulate a person before New Year comes?

After 23:59:99 on the 1st of January we can say *Happy New Year* - С Новым Годом!

Comment: **Happy New Year!** But if you don't translate the Russian greeting (is it in the title?) we'll never know for sure.

Comment: Happy New Year is said after 23:59:99 of this year, I mean when 1st of January starts. But what do we say before that?

Comment: No, you can wish someone a  Happy New Year *before* 00.00. Do you wish someone a Merry Christmas *only* on December 25th?

Comment: @Mari-LouA No, we wish a Merry Christmas on the 7th of January. Before that we say With upcoming Merry Christmas if translate from russian.

Comment: Agreed with Mari-Lou: we say "Happy New Year!" for days or even weeks before January 1.

Comment: So there is no forthcoming or upcoming congratulations?

Comment: Well, you can certainly longer ways wish someone well in the upcoming year but it's more common to just say "happy new year".

Comment: @SovereignSun - No, we don't specifically say congratulations on the *forthcoming* or *upcoming* New Year.  It is certainly possible to say "Congratulations on your upcoming ______!" but for New Year's, it's just "Happy New Year!"

Comment: @Mari-LouA  "С Новым Годом" literally translates to "Новым" (new) "Годом" (year) the "C" is the preposition that is used to show "going in". The Russians celebrate Christmas on January 7th due to the Orthodox calendar.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's just plain ole

### Happy New Year!

Anglophones begin wishing each other *Happy New Year* more or less the same time as Christmas.

> **Merry Christmas** ***and*** **a Happy New Year!**

[image]

[Google images](https://www.google.co.uk/search?q=%22merry%20christmas%20and%20happy%20new%20year%22&biw=1242&bih=580&source=lnms&tbm=isch&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwiW6Mzr657RAhUJMlAKHTr8BtAQ_AUIBigB)

Hmm... I can sense the OP's disappointment

OK. In Scotland the last day of the old year is called

### Hogmanay

> The roots of Hogmanay perhaps reach back to the celebration of the winter solstice among the Norse, as well as incorporating customs from the Gaelic celebration of Samhain. The Vikings celebrated *Yule*, which later contributed to the *Twelve Days of Christmas*, or the "Daft Days" as they were sometimes called in Scotland. **Christmas was not celebrated as a festival and Hogmanay was the more traditional celebration in Scotland**. This may have been a result of the Protestant Reformation after which Christmas was seen as "too Papist"

*[Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hogmanay)*

Comment: [What is Hogmanay? When Scots drink whiskey, set stuff on fire and jump in the river](http://metro.co.uk/2016/12/31/what-is-hogmanay-when-scots-drink-whiskey-set-stuff-on-fire-and-jump-in-the-river-6353386/)

Comment: +1 Just to be clear [**Hogmanay**](https://www.edinburghshogmanay.com)  is the name of the celebration, it's not what one says in place of "Happy New Year!" The burning stuff is due to the Vikings, the drinking stuff is because they (Scots) make whiskey and it's close at hand, and the jumping in the river is because they're nutters!